# Plank cut-list calculator

Tags: python

So I've just finished my first Python module (and published on Github), with this little project I'd like to learn how to distribute my code so that other users can use it as a plug in for their own projects.

Specifically I'm looking for feedback in the following direction:

- Is the interface to the module designed correctly?
- At the beginning of the code I check for completeness of the input, is this the best way to handle errors? (It looks chunky)
- Is the repository set up correctly so that it is plug-and-play?
- In general, is this the best way to design a module or should I work with classes instead of funtions?

Any other feedback is also welcome :)

Thanks in advance!

---

Link to Github repository: https://github.com/nick-van-h/cutlistcalculator

__main__.py:

```py
from cutlist import getCutLists
import sys
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Argument parser
    text = "This program calculates the most optimal cutlist for beams and planks."
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=text)
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="custom location of input json file (e.g. 'localhost:8080/foo/bar.json'", default="")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="custom location of output folder (e.g. 'localhost:8080/foo' -> 'localhost:8080/foo/cutlist_result.json'", default="")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #Kick-off
    result = getCutLists(args.input, args.output)

    #Exit function with VS Code workaround
    try:
        sys.exit(result)
    except:
        print(result)
```

cutlist.py:

```
import json
from operator import itemgetter
import copy
from pathlib import Path
import os

def getSolution(reqs, combs):
    needs = copy.deepcopy(reqs)
    res = []
    res.append([])
    for comb in combs:
        #As long as all items from comb[x] fulfill need
        combNeed = True
        while combNeed:
            #Check if comb[x] provides more than need (fail fast)
            for need in needs:
                if comb[need['Length']] > need['Qty']:
                    combNeed = False
            if not combNeed:
                break

            for need in needs:
                need['Qty'] -= comb[need['Length']]

            #Append result
            res[0].append(comb.copy())

    #Calculate total price
    for sol in res:
        price = round(sum(x['Price'] for x in sol),2)

    res.append([price])

    #Return result
    return res

def getCutLists(inputstr = "", outputstr = ""):
    if inputstr:
        jsonlocation = inputstr
    else:
        jsonlocation = './input/input.json' #default input location
    print(jsonlocation)
    errstr = ""

    #Get input
    try:
        with open(jsonlocation) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except:
        errstr += "JSON file not found. "
        return(f"Err: {errstr}")

    #Get variables from JSON object
    try:
        reqs = data['Required Lengths']
    except:
        errstr += "'Required Lengths' not found. "

    try:
        avail = data['Available base material']
    except:
        errstr += "'Available base material' not found. "

    try:
        cutwidth = data['Cut loss']
    except:
        errstr += "'Cut loss' not found. "

    if errstr:
        return(f"Err: {errstr}")

    #Test for required keys in array
    try:
        test = [x['Length'] for x in reqs]
        if min(test) <= 0:
            errstr += f"Err: Required length ({min(test)}) must be bigger than 0."
    except:
        errstr += "'Length' not found in required lengths. "

    try:
        test = [x['Qty'] for x in reqs]
        if min(test) <= 0:
            errstr += f"Err: Required quantity ({min(test)}) must be bigger than 0."
    except:
        errstr += "'Qty' not found in required lengths. "

    try:
        test = [x['Length'] for x in avail]
        if min(test) <= 0:
            errstr += f"Err: Available length ({min(test)}) must be bigger than 0."
    except:
        errstr += "'Length' not found in available base material. "

    try:
        test = [x['Price'] for x in avail]
        if min(test) < 0:
            errstr += f"Err: Available price ({min(test)}) can't be negative."
    except:
        errstr += "'Price' not found in available base material. "

    if errstr:
        return(f"Err: {errstr}")


    #Init other vars
    listreq = [x['Length'] for x in reqs]
    listavail = [x['Length'] for x in avail]
    minreq = min(listreq)
    res=[]

    #Error handling on passed inputs
    if max(listreq) > max(listavail):
        return(f"Err: Unable to process, required length of {max(listreq)} is bigger than longest available base material with length of {max(listavail)}.")

    if cutwidth < 0:
        return(f"Err: Cut width can't be negative")

    #Make list of all available cut combinations
    combs = []
    for plank in avail:
        myplank = plank.copy()
        for cut in reqs:
            myplank[cut['Length']] = 0

        #Increase first required plank length
        myplank[reqs[0]['Length']] += 1

        #Set other variables
        myplank['Unitprice'] = myplank['Price'] / myplank['Length']

        filling = True
        while filling:
            #Calculate rest length
            myplank['Rest'] = myplank['Length']
            for i in reqs:
                length = i['Length']
                myplank['Rest'] -= ((myplank[length] * length) + (myplank[length] * cutwidth))
            myplank['Rest'] += cutwidth

            #Set rest of variables
            myplank['Baseprice'] = (myplank['Price']) / ((myplank['Length'] - myplank['Rest']))
            myplank['Optimal'] = (myplank['Rest'] <= minreq)


            #Check if rest length is positive
            if myplank['Rest'] >= 0:
                combs.append(myplank.copy())
                myplank[reqs[0]['Length']] += 1
            else:
                for i in range(len(reqs)):
                    if myplank[reqs[i]['Length']] > 0:
                        myplank[reqs[i]['Length']] = 0
                        if i < len(reqs)-1:
                            myplank[reqs[i+1]['Length']] += 1
                            break
                        else:
                            filling = False

    #Sort combinations descending by remaining length, get solution
    combs = sorted(combs, key=lambda k: k['Rest'])
    res.append(getSolution(reqs, combs))

    #Sort combinations by getting biggest lengths first (largest to smallest), optimal pieces first, get solution
    listreq = sorted(listreq, reverse=True)
    listreq.insert(0,'Optimal')
    for x in reversed(listreq):
        combs.sort(key=itemgetter(x), reverse=True)
    res.append(getSolution(reqs, combs))

    #Sort combination by least effective price per unit, get solution
    combs = sorted(combs, key=lambda k: k['Baseprice'])
    res.append(getSolution(reqs, combs))

    #Get cheapest option & make readable format
    cheapest = min([x[1] for x in res])
    for x in res:
        if x[1] == cheapest:
            sol = {}
            sol['Required base material'] = {}
            sol['Cut list'] = []
            i = 1
            for plank in x[0]:
                if plank['Length'] not in sol['Required base material']:
                    sol['Required base material'][plank['Length']] = 0
                sol['Required base material'][plank['Length']] += 1
                str = f"Plank {i}: Length {plank['Length']}, "
                for req in reqs:
                    if plank[req['Length']] > 0: str += f"{plank[req['Length']]}x {req['Length']}, "
                str += f"rest: {plank['Rest']}"
                sol['Cut list'].append(str)
                i += 1

            sol['Total price'] = cheapest
            break

    #Get output location
    if outputstr:
        outputfile = outputstr
        if outputfile[len(outputfile)-1] != "//":
            outputfile += "//"
        outputfile += "cutlist_result.json"
    else:
        outputfile = "./output/cutlist_result.json"

    #Make directories
    Path(os.path.dirname(outputfile)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    #Output to file
    f = open(outputfile, "w")
    json.dump(sol, f, indent=4)
    f.close

    return("Success")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Locations

The location documentation is confusing. In `getCutLists`, the input defaults to

```
'./input/input.json'
```

but in your `main`, the example in the documentation is

```
'localhost:8080/foo/bar.json'
```

Is this a file path or a URL? Based on your usage it looks like it must be a file path, and the host and port shown above should not be there. Also, `'./input/input.json'` should just be made the default value of `inputstr`, not `""`.

### Function names

In Python, the standard for function and variable names is lower_snake_case, i.e. `get_cut_lists`, `get_solution`, etc.

### Function complexity

`getCutLists` should be broken into at least three different functions for maintainability, testability and legibility.

### Exception handling

Do not degrade exceptions to strings like this:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    errstr += "JSON file not found. "
    return(f"Err: {errstr}")
```

There is a handful of problems with this pattern. First, `except:` interferes with the user's ability to Ctrl+C break out of the program. Also, `except:` is too broad in general, and you should only catch what you expect the code to throw, in this case `FileNotFoundError`. Also, if you wanted your error string to be useful, you would include the name of the file. Finally, all of that machinery should go away and you should simply `open()` and let the exception fall through to the caller without an `except`. If the caller wants to re-format the way that exceptions are printed on the upper level, it can; but that should not be the responsibility of this function. A pattern to avoid in languages with good exception handling is to degrade that exception handling into scalar return values (string, bool, int error codes, etc.)

As for validation like this:

```
try:
    test = [x['Length'] for x in reqs]
    if min(test) <= 0:
        errstr += f"Err: Required length ({min(test)}) must be bigger than 0."
except:
    errstr += "'Length' not found in required lengths. "
```

Raise your own exception instead:

```
min_len = min(x['Length'] for x in reqs)
if min_len <= 0:
    raise ValueError(f'Required length ({min_len}) must be greater than 0.')
```

Also don't make a temporary list; apply `min` directly to the generator.

### Comments

Whereas

```
#Make list of all available cut combinations
```

is a useful comment,

```
#Set other variables
```

is not. It's worse than having no comment at all. If there's something complex or surprising going on, or something to do with business logic, document it; otherwise avoid

```
# do the thing
do_thing()
```

### Expression simplification

```
((myplank[length] * length) + (myplank[length] * cutwidth))
```

can be

```
myplank[length]*(length + cut_width)
```

### Weakly-typed structures

You're loading from JSON; fine: but then you never unpack the dictionary representation of your data to objects; you leave it in dictionaries. This leads to code like

```
        myplank['Baseprice'] = (myplank['Price']) / ((myplank['Length'] - myplank['Rest']))
```

which is a mess. Instead, make actual classes to represent your data, and unpack to those.

In other words, we aren't in Javascript: not everything is a dictionary.

### Mixed os/path

```
Path(os.path.dirname(outputfile)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

uses mixed `Path` (good) and `os` calls (not so good). You do not need `dirname` here; instead make `outputfile` a path directly and then manipulate that.

Comment: This is so much more than I've hoped for, thanks a lot! Especially the part about raising my own error codes hasn't occurred to me. Regarding loading from JSON; do you suggest a more rigid method then?

Comment: JSON itself is fine for storage, but when you deserialize it, it's better if you do it to actual classes. There are easy and hard ways to do this - an easy way is to call `cls(**dict)` on a class that is marked `@dataclass`.

Answer (score 3):

## source directory

Put the module in a separate source directory. This has the advantage that you can install this directory separately with `pip install -e` for example, or by adding it to a `.pth` in your virtual environments site-packages. You are using virtual environments for the development?

## tools

Use a good IDE, and the tools available to improve your code. I use `black` as code formatter, `mypy` with a strict configuration to check for typing errors, `pydocstyle` to check my docstrings, `pytest` for unit tests, `pyflakes` for other errors. Get to know them, look for configuration inspiration to larger python projects, and integrate them in your workflow. Most IDEs make this really simple.

## variable names

In python, the length of the variable names has no influence on the performance of the program. then pick clear variable names like `requested_planks` instead or `reqs`. Decyphering your code is really difficult, due to these unclear names.

## split in functions

You have 2 functions already, but this code needs a lot more.

- reads the input
- validates the input
- makes combinations
- picks a combination
- outputs to an output file

Each of these deserves its own function. Doing so allows you to better document this, test the different parts and make changes in the future.

I try to separate my functions so the data transferred is clear.

## read the inputs

Hoist your IO (talks: [1](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#clean-architecture-python) [2](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#hoist))
Don't pass along the input file. read the input file in your `main()`, function and pass the contents on to the validator and later calculations. Same goes for the output. The calculation returns the required planks, and then the `main()` function writes the result to disk if needed.

## validate the input

Your input validation is spread around the main method. You also communicate with strings. An alternative is to communicate a validation failure with a `ValueError`

If you add in type hints and docstring you could end up with something like this:

```
import typing


class Plank(typing.NamedTuple):
    """Requested plank."""

    Length: float
    Qty: int


class BasePlank(typing.NamedTuple):
    """Available base plank."""

    Length: float
    Price: float  # or Decimal?


InputData = typing.TypedDict(
    InputData,
    {
        "Cut loss": float,
        "Required Lengths": typing.List[Plank],
        "Available base material": typing.List[BasePlank],
    },
)


def validate_planks(planks: typing.Iterable[Plank]) -> None:
    """Validate the requested planks.

    - Length must be larger than 0
    - Quantity must be larger than 0
    """
    for plank in planks:
        if "Length" not in plank:
            raise ValueError(f"`Length` not found in {plank}")
        if "Qty" not in plank:
            raise ValueError(f"`Qty` not found in {plank}")
        if plank["Length"] < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"`Length` < 0 in {plank}")
        if plank["Qty"] < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"`Qty` < 0 in {plank}")


def validate_baseplanks(planks: typing.Iterable[BasePlank],) -> None:
    """Validate the available base planks.

    - Length must be larger than 0
    - price must not be negative
    """
    for plank in planks:
        if "Length" not in plank:
            raise ValueError(f"`Length` not found in {plank}")
        if "Qty" not in plank:
            raise ValueError(f"`Qty` not found in {plank}")
        if plank["Length"] < 0:
            raise ValueError(f"`Length` < 0 in {plank}")
        if plank["Price"] <= 0:
            raise ValueError(f"negative `Price` in {plank}")


def validate_input(input_data: InputData) -> None:
    """Validate the input."""

    if "Cut loss" not in input_data:
        raise ValueError("`Cut loss` not found.")
    if "Available base material" not in input_data:
        raise ValueError("`Available base material` not found.")
    baseplanks = input_data["Available base material"]
    validate_baseplanks(baseplanks)

    if "Required Lengths" not in input_data:
        raise ValueError("`Required Lengths` not found.")
    planks = input_data["Required Lengths"]
    validate_planks(planks)

    if max(plank["Length"] for plank in planks) > max(
        plank[Length] for plank in baseplanks
    ):
        raise ValueError(
            "Maximum requested piece is longer than longest base plank"
        )
```

### `jsonschema`

Or you can use `jsonschema` to do the validation for you:

```
schema = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "Cut loss": {"type": "number", "minimum": 0},
            "Required Lengths": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Length": {"type": "number", "exclusiveMinimum": 0},
                        "Qty": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "exclusiveMinimum": 0,
                            "multipleOf": 1,
                        },
                    },
                    "required": ["Length", "Qty"],
                },
            },
            "Available base material": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Length": {"type": "number", "exclusiveMinimum": 0},
                        "Price": {"type": "number", "minimum": 0},
                    },
                    "required": ["Length", "Price"],
                },
                "minProperties": 1,
            },
            "required": [
                "Cut loss",
                "Available base material",
                "Required Lengths",
            ],
        },
    }
)
```

and then use

```
errors = list(schema.iter_errors(data))
```

Having validated your input data, you can choose to put them in classes, but for this solution that might be a bit too much.

## testing

This way you can test your validation separately.

In a separate directory `tests`, file `test_cutlist.py` or in a separate file per function you want to test

```
import pytest

def test_validatbaseplanks():
    correct_data = [
        {
            "Length": 300,
            "Price": 5.95
        },
        {
            "Length": 180,
            "Price": 2.95
        },
        {
            "Length": 360,
            "Price": 6.95
        }
    ]
    cutlistcalculator.validate_baseplanks(correct_data)

    missing_price = [
        {
            "Length": 300,
        },
        {
            "Length": 180,
            "Price": 2.95
        },
        {
            "Length": 360,
            "Price": 6.95
        }
    ]
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as excinfo:
        cutlistcalculator.validate_baseplanks(correct_data)
    assert "`Price` not found" in str(excinfo.value)
```

etcetera.

## JSON

Think about what format you want to serialize the input and output. You use `JSON`, but as you noticed, this has a few downsides. It is very verbose, and you can'y add comments. JSON is meant to be easily read by a computer. Alternatives are `BSON`, `TOML`, ...

I'm not saying these are better, but at least take a look at it. Especially when you are so early in the development, it is easy to switch.

On the other hand, if you partition your code correctly, and make the parsing of the input its own function, you can later easily change the input or aoutput format. You could even foresee multiple parsers, and accept different formats.

## calculation

I don't get the algorithm you use. I don't have too much time to figure it out, but the way you use unclear names and have it all in 1 large blob doesn't help. Try to partition it in logical structures that you refactor to separate functions. Carefully name the functions, and foresee a docstring and type hnts. Once you have that, post them again as a new question.

Make a function that generates possible cut plans, with only the required planks and available baseplanks as input. Make this a generator, that yields a possible combination. You can the pipe this into a function that calculates the cost of this arrangement. This takes one single combination and the  prices of the baseplanks as arguments, and returns the cost of the combination. By splitting the work like this, you can document their behaviour , and can test each of these components separately.

## output

Separate this from the code that calculates the best solution

use a `with` statement to construct a context.

```
with output_file.open("w") as filehandle:
    json.dump(filehandle, result, indent=2)
```

## Conclusion

I know this is a lot, but try to incorporate these tips, and the ones from Reinderien, and then if you're unsure come back with a new version. Keep up the good work